# Wait for form response after submitting with button.click()

Tags: puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to submit a form and I can't figure out how to wait for the response because the normal approaches don't work.

Submitting must be done by invoking `click()` on the submit button rather than calling `form.submit()` which on this webpage results in an error that I can't control. Therefore, this does not work:

```
await page.$eval('#form', form => form.submit);
```

Submitting the form does not navigate to a new page, but rather modifies the HTML in place. I have also tried `waitForNavigation` with every `waitUntil` option, none works.

Are there any other approaches I can try? Thanks

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1278) helpful at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Submitting the form does not navigate to a new page, but rather modifies the HTML in place.

In this case you can wait for a css selector via [page.waitForSelector](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options)

For example if a success message is shown above your form after a successful submit, just wait for this css selector to appear in the dom:

```
await page.waitForSelector('form div.success');
```